# Counting non-isomorphic trees from a degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have the degree sequence $(5,4,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$. This is a tree, and a simple representation is:

[image]

(My intuition says that any degree sequence that corresponds to a tree can be laid out like this in a [caterpillar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree). [@David demonstrated that is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145075)).

**Question:**
Is there a good approach to counting all possible non-isomorphic trees that have this degree sequence?

**Easier question:** (which I would still like to see a good approach for)
How many non-isomorphic caterpillar graphs have this degree sequence?

Comment: Re "My intuition says...": see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145075).

Comment: I see there is [a generic version of this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37665/degree-sequences-and-graph-enumeration) on math***overflow***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's not going to be a clever way to do this.  Using `geng 14 13:13 -c` (the package `geng` comes with Nauty), we can generate representatives from each isomorphism class of 14-vertex trees.  I wrote a [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) script to identify the ones with the degree sequence `[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]`. It turns out there's 150 of them, drawn below (with the vertices ascribed their degrees):

[image]

Comment: Impressive result! thanks for investigating and persisting to this outcome.

Comment: My favorites are graph 112 (last on row 28) and graph 145 (first on row 37) :-)

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones See the java programs in this  link: https://github.com/manofdalmasca/thesis-code.  But I don't know how to call the function in the java program that generates all non-isomorphic trees by a degree sequence yet. (This may be quicker, but I can't guarantee it)