# Any tree degree sequence is a caterpillar degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145024) Joffan comments

> My intuition says that any degree sequence that corresponds to a tree can be laid out... in a [caterpillar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree). That would be cool to have a proof of.

So I am asking and answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

**Theorem**.  Given any tree, there is a [caterpillar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree) with the same degree sequence.

**Proof**.  Suppose the degree sequence consists of $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_s$, all greater than or equal to $2$, and $e$ elements equal to $1$.  This is the degree sequence of a tree so we have
$$\langle\hbox{total degree}\rangle
  =2\langle\hbox{number of edges}\rangle
  =2\langle\hbox{number of vertices}\rangle-2\ ,$$
which gives
$$d_1+\cdots+d_s+e=2s+2e-2$$
and hence
$$e=d_1+\cdots+d_s-2s+2\ .$$
Now it is clear that the vertices of degree $d_1,\ldots,d_s$ can be formed into a chain with $s-1$ edges, and so the number of "available" edges is
$$d_1+\cdots+d_s-2(s-1)\ ,$$
which is exactly $e$.  So all the vertices of degree $1$ can be fitted around this chain, forming a caterpillar.

Comment: Good analysis, thanks